# Not able to load library stylesheets via webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack for bundling my angular1 js project. I was trying to use libraries like bootstrap, angular-bootstrap-calendar etc... I have installed the libraries using npm. But I happen to notice that the  stylesheets associated with the libraries weren't loading at all. I was using scss loaders for loading my stylesheets. My webpack config is

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    vendor: ['angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'angular-bootstrap-calendar']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/js',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style!css!sass"
      }
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js"),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      moment: "moment"
    })
  ]
};
```

Am I in short of any loaders here or do I need to add more configuration?

Comment: are you including styles from bootstrap? like `require('bootstrap/bootstrap.css');`

Comment: @JAG I am importing my styles in index.html like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='node_modules/bootstrap-only-css/dist/bootstrap.css'>
    <link href="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">`. But I guess thats not the correct way to do it.